# Salesforce Lookup Custom Field ID

Tags: custom-field, order

I am creating an order, using the API.

I have a field of type look up for account. Do I have to send an account ID or can I just send an account name? My logic has no way of looking up accounts by ID right now.

POST https://na82.salesforce.com/services/data/v30.0/commerce/sale/order

```
{"order": "Ship_To__c:" "Joe Jones"}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Lookup fields store an Id in the database, and so must be populated with a valid Id for the object the lookup field points to (Account, in your example).

Displaying the related record's name is just something that Salesforce does in the UI (classic and lightning) as a UX (User eXperience) nicety.